# How to migrate from Git to TFVC on Azure devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfvc

I was asked to migrate the source code from TFS to Azure DevOps with the following requirements:

- There are going to be two development teams.
- The first team will use Git the version control tool.
- The second team will use TFVC as their version control tool.

The thing is now that both teams are currently using TFS and I migrated all their projects from TFS to Git using [rtc2gitcli](https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2gitcli), **but** I couldn't find a way to migrate a **Git** repo to a **TFVC** repo(**With history**).

The question is how to move the code and history from my Git repositories to TFVC, to achieve what is required.

Comment: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

Comment: Old thread but just wanted to know if you found a solution? If you used the tool git-tfs - how did you use it?